# Avoid CEDET 2.0 for CEDET 1.1 on emacs 24.3

Tags: emacs, cedet

I tried to install cedet 1.1 on emacs but when I init cedet this
error occur. How to unload CEDET Version 2.0 and load CEDET 1.1?
I used Ubuntu 12.04 or Fedora 19.

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `/home/robin/.emacs':

error: CEDET Version 2.0 already loaded.

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the `--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace.
```

This is my initialization in my .emacs

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/cedet-1.1/")
(load-file "~/.emacs.d/cedet-1.1/common/cedet.el")
(setq semantic-load-turn-useful-things-on t)
(global-ede-mode 1)
(global-srecode-minor-mode 1)
(semantic-mode 1)

(require 'semantic/ia)
```

Comment: Why do you want to replace Cedet 2?

Comment: because i need semantic-make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to load CEDET 1.1 as first package in your Emacs initialization file - before loading any package. Please, take into account, that on some Linuxes, some system-wide packages are loaded & they could load CEDET 2.0 before loading your initialization file.

Comment: I tried to rename my cedet folder in emacs-24.3/lisp/cedet to emacs-24.3/lisp/old-cedet but he tells me again CEDET Version 2.0 already load.

Comment: which OS are you using? I suggest to start Emacs with `-q --no-site-file`, try to load CEDET 1.1 from the `*scratch*` buffer & check how it works. If it's loaded without problem, then try to run with `-q` only, and try again - if it loads, then you need to put loading of the CEDET 1.1 in the begin of your `~/.emacs` file

Comment: Hi, I find my mistake, I doesn't load cedet 1.1 because I tried to load ecb before. thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using an old version of CEDET, you could try finding the equivalent functionality for CEDET 2.0.

I think in this case, it is a matter of changing

`(require 'semantic-make)`

to

`(require 'semantic/bovine/make)`

Comment: Hi, i want to load Emacs IDE Frame Tools http://sourceforge.net/projects/ideframetools/ . When i add (require 'semantic/bovine/make) that doesn't works.

Comment: Basically all the cedet related requires need to change from `semantic-*` to either `semantic/bovine/*` if they are related to parsers or `semantic/*` if they are more general parts of semantic. Or you can try just commenting out the requires, since most of the cedet entry points are autoloaded in Emacs 24.x.